# Why does phpMyAdmin say that the primary key and the UNIQUE constraint are indexes?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Based on my understanding:

- A primary key is a constraint that prevents duplicate values in
  a column, same thing for the UNIQUE constraint.
- An index is a data structure that is used by the DBMS to speed up the
  querying performance.

But why does phpMyAdmin say that the primary key and the UNIQUE constraint are indexes?:

[image]

Comment: "A primary key is a constraint that prevents duplicate values in a column, same thing for the UNIQUE constraint." A `primary key` and `unique` key can also speed up query performance because both are also indexed..

Answer (score 0):

Because they are.

When you insert a new row and there's a `UNIQUE` defined on some column, the database engine has to look through the values already stored in the column to decide if the inserted value collides with something already stored. That process is simplified greatly with an index. This is why all common DB vendors implement unique constraints (`UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`, etc.) as indexes (or back them up with indexes).

The general idea is that PKs, unique constraints, indexes, unique indexes, partial indexes, etc. are all related. They just have slightly different properties (normal indexes do not throw an error on duplicates whereas unique indexes do). That's why you usually find information on PKs and unique constraints in `information_schema.indexes`.